# Weird White Screen on Laravel Routes ("/")

Tags: php, laravel, wsod

From the title itself, I have a weird Laravel bug. I have test page for my home page which has a route name of "main". It works perfectly fine. However, when I tried to change it from route::get("main") to route::get("/") I end up with a white page. No errors, when I view source, no code or whatsoever. I am running Laravel 5.6

```
// Landing Page actual Route
// White Page 

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('templates.landing-blank');
});

// Landing Page
// Works Perfectly.

Route::get('main', function() {
    return view('templates.landing-blank');
});
```

Is this something related to htaccess? I already doubled checked everything and copied the htaccess but still no avail. I also did a composer update and the problems still persist.

Comment: Try to clear the cahce by `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`. And give write permission to `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` directories. @drake24

Comment: @Zane still doesn't work.By bootstrap/cache and storage perfectly works. It

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of the `Route::get` should be the the url path to access the page, so "main" would be accessed by `example.com/main` and "/" would be just `example.com`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I got your point. It works perfectly fine, but I need a route that doesn't have any text. only the "root" which is "/"  and yes. "/" is www.example.com. And it seems it returns a white page :(

Comment: Oh okay, yeah that's weird, with www.example.com/main you said it's working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to **.env** and change the label **APP_DEBUG** to "**true**"?
Maybe you can see the error.

And I think you need to add a "/" to the "main" route.
Like that:

```
Route::get('/main', function() {
    return view('templates.landing-blank');
});
```

Comment: I got your point. It works but I need a route that doesn't have any text. only the "root" which is "/"

Comment: But I think if you do this:

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('templates.landing-blank');
});

Route::get('/main', function() {
    return view('templates.landing-blank');
});